# malloc twice for structure

Tags: c, structure

I have a structure as below

```
typedef struct Mystruct{
char *name;
int telno;
struct Mystruct *nextp;
}data;
```

Now I malloc the structure

```
data *addnode;
addnode = malloc (sizeof(data));
```

Now I would add data to the `char *name`.

```
addnode->name = malloc (sizeof(MAX));
```

**Question**:Why is it required to `malloc` again?

I was under the assumption that `malloc`-ing the `addnode` will even allocate the memory for `addnode->name` but it is not so.

Comment: The first `malloc` just allocate the memory to store pointer of `char *name` ..

Comment: Supposing your assumption was correct, and `malloc` allocated space for `name` to point to, how would it know that `MAX` is the size you need? It doesn't know, so it cannot possibly do what you want.

Comment: If you know the length of the name beforehand (or at least a maximum possible length) you could use `char name[MAX]` insteat of `char* name`. Then you do not need to malloc again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocating memory for `Mystruct` provides enough memory for a pointer to `name`.  At this point we have no idea how many characters will be in a name so can't possibly allocate the memory for it.

If you want to fully allocate the structure in a single allocation, you could decide on a max size for `name` and change the structure definition to

```
#define MAX_NAME (10) /* change this as required */
typedef struct Mystruct{
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    int telno;
    struct Mystruct *nextp;
}data;
```

Or, if you know the name when you allocate the struct, you could hide the need for two allocations from the caller by providing a constructor function

```
struct Mystruct* Mystruct_create(const char* name)
{
    Mystruct* ms = malloc(sizeof(*ms));
    ms->name = strdup(name);
    return ms;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` is not deep and doesn't do recursion. So it won't allocate memory for any of the pointers inside the structure you pass.

If you think about this a bit more, you can see that must be so. You don't pass in any information about the structure you are allocating. You just pass a size for the memory block. Now, `malloc` doesn't even know what type of data you are allocating. It doesn't know that the block itself contains a pointer.

As for why this design choice was made, how can the library tell who owns the memory that your pointer refers to? Perhaps it's owned by that structure. Or perhaps you want to use that pointer to refer to some memory allocated elsewhere. Only you can know that which is why the responsibility falls to you. In fact your structure is a fine example of this. Probably the `name` member is owned by the structure, and the `nextp` member is not.

Answer (score 1):

No. first `malloc()` allocates memory to whole structure including memory for holding pointer to name. i.e 4 bytes in 32 bit OS.

You need to allocate memory separately for holding data in it. by default that pointer will be pointing to some garbage location, if not initialized.

same case for `free()` too. i.e you have to free the inner blocks first, then free the memory for whole structure. There is no recursion kind of things in `malloc() and free()`.